# Grails 2.3 expression output error in g:javascript environment

Tags: json, grails, gsp

I recently updated my Grails installation from 2.2 to 2.3.1 and encountered an error while trying to use a groovy expression inside a `<g:javascript>` environment to get some json data structure.

This is an example:

```
<g:javascript>
  var foo = ${ bar as grails.converters.JSON };
  doSomeStuff();
</g:javascript>
```

This will escape the whole JSON-string to unicode chars (`\u005b\u007bid:1\u002c name:.....`). How is it possible to get the raw string. As the documentation pointed out: I tried using the [`raw()`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#xssPrevention) keyword. But had no luck. I didn't changed any of my XSS-related configs. Thats my config:

```
grails.views.default.codec = "none"
grails.views.gsp.encoding = "UTF-8"
grails.converters.encoding = "UTF-8"
```

---

Edit:

My temporary solution till this bug is fixed:

`$.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(uglyUnicodeString))`

Comment: It seems that `<g:javascript>` should have an option to output raw content. Could you open a JIRA with an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. See this issue and the linked ones:

http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10641

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My solution was:

```
<g:javascript>
    var foo = ${ bar.encodeAsJSON() };
    doSomeStuff();
</g:javascript>
```